# Two Fragments overlapping each other

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am using a `BottomNavigationView` for a Tab-Interface in my main activity. in `onCreate()`, the switchTab method is called with the initial fragment. Tapping the the bottom navigation calls `switchTab()` for the respective tabs and should hide the current and display the new one. If the fragment was not added to the `SupportFragmentManager`, it gets added, otherwise it will be shown. Here's my code snippet:

```
private fun switchTab(fragment: Fragment, tag: String): Boolean {
    val currentFragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments.find { it.tag == tag }

    val ta = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    if (currentFragment != null) {
        ta.hide(currentFragment)
    }

    if (supportFragmentManager.fragments.contains(fragment)) {
        ta.show(fragment)
    } else {
        ta.add(R.id.contentContainer, fragment, tag)
    }

    ta.commit()
    return true
}
```

Now the problem is that sometimes two fragments are visible and overlay each other, making the userinterface unusable. How can this happen?

Comment: Why not using replace instead of add?

Comment: because it replace ends the lifecycle of the fragment. for faster tab switching, I wanted to keep the fragments and only hide them.

Comment: Do you have solid background color added for each fragment on their root layout?

Comment: currently I don't. that is a good workaround, but still it is not clear to me why it works most of the time but sometimes fails